# Pip install doesn't install .so files my own library created using setuptools?

Tags: python

I created a python library using setuptools that contains `.so` files. When I try to `pip install` the library the `.so` files aren't being installed into my virtual environment.

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to produce more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your question, as it stands, is somewhat vague so I can't be sure if I'm answering it. However, from the `setup.py` which you've pasted as a comment, I think you've not specified how to build the extension locally. Putting the `.so` directly as part of your package is not very wise since it's not cross platform. The opposite approach is to compile it on the target machine but they'll need a compiler toolchain locally installed.

Please refer to the example [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/extending/building.html#building-c-and-c-extensions-with-distutils) which describes how to include C extensions in your project.The official python packaging page on this topic is incomplete and there's an issue describing this [over here](https://github.com/pypa/packaging.python.org/issues/284). You might find something useful there as well.